# Insert value into db.json with help of angular-resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, angular-resource

I have a json file named db.json which is like

```
{
"menu":[
 {
   "id":0,
   "item":"item1"
},{
   "id":1,
   "item":"item2"
},{
   "id":2,
   "item":"item3"
}
],
"feedback":[]
}
```

I am using angular `$resource` to `PUT` an Javascirpt object into the `feedback` array.

Here is my service code-

```
this.getFeedbacks = function(){
            return $resource(baseURL + "feedback/:id", null, {
                'update': {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            });
        };
```

And here is the controller code-

```
$scope.fb.push($scope.myFeedback);
 menuFactory.getFeedbacks().update({
            id: $scope.fb.id
        }, $scope.fb);
```

Notice that the `feedback` array in the json is empty and the $scope.myFeedback is found from a ng-controller's ng-model and this ng-controller has a submit button when I click on the submit button then the values of the inputs are stored into the json file.

The HTML code is-

```
<form name="feedbackForm" ng-submit="setFeedback()">
   <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="myFeedback.name">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="feedback">
</form>
```

My update function is not working why please someone explain it.
Note that I am very beginner at angularJS platform and REST client-server networking.

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle for better understanding?

Comment: You can't post data to a static resource file. That file can only be modified by a server side programming language. What is value of `baseUrl`?

Comment: I said i am very beginner at this sector. I just want to save the value in the json file which I find from name text field.

Comment: What programming language is your server running?

Comment: I am using json-server

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is an exercise from Coursera. Here is my solution.

Instead of using the 'update', you should use 'save' method from $resource to add data into db,json file.

in your controller, say:

```
menuFactory.getFeedbacks().save($scope.feedback);
```

$scope.feedback should be the name you used in the feedback form object

Hope this answer help you!

Comment: And the code in your service can be simplified to this(no need to use customized PUT request): <br/> this.getFeedbacks = function(){
            return $resource(baseURL + "feedback");
        };

Answer (score 0):

First of all, watch browser console. It often gives you hints, where to look for the error. Coming back to the problem: try using `$update` instead of `update`.